# Bootstrap Datepicker, Start date Format Not set

Tags: datepicker, angular, bootstrap-datepicker

When I am using bootstrap datepicker i need to set start state on 
   01/01/1930.But Format only allows when i gave count of days format.

```
 startDate: '-31578d', (working)
```

But Its not working when I use direct date format. Anyone plzzz help me

```
 startDate: '01/01/1930', (not working)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the format parameter along the startDate,

```
   format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
   startDate:..
```

Answer (score 0):

But Already I written code,

```
 .datepicker({
            showOnFocus: true,
            showOn: "button",
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            startDate: '-31582d',
            endDate: '+0d',                
            autoclose: true
        })
```